# Width 100% to full size issues

Tags: html, css, width, gallery, accordion

I made a 100% to full size div in order to make some vertical accordion gallery. It actually works, the only problem is that the animation of resizing is weird, it flattens my picture during the resizing as you can see there: http://hine.be/test

Do u have any idea on how I could fix it ? here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  
<style>
input{display:none}
.ani
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:url(paonad.jpg) center no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
transition:all 2s;
-moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
display:block;
}
input:checked + .ani
{
height:400px;
background-size: 4000px 400px;
}

.ani2
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:url(spacingad.jpg) center no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
transition:all 2s;
-moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
display:block;
}
input:checked + .ani2
{
height:400px;
background-size: 4000px 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="paon">
<label class="ani" for="paon"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="space">
<label class="ani2" for="space"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit : http://jsfiddle.net/ht5F8/

Thanks to Lowkase !

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten"?  Do you mean the image resizes along with the browser width?

Comment: @Lowkase I mean that during the resizing animation the height of the div goes by 0 instead of constantly increasing.

Comment: O, I see you need to click on the images and that starts the CSS transition.  Then the images are going back to their original size the height goes down to 0, which in effect "flattens" the image.

Comment: @Lowkase exactly but how can I prevent the image to flatten during the animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it Oreki:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzB3E/

In your .ani classes you need to specify your min height like this:

```
background-size: 100% 100px;
```

Instead of this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

I also stumbled on a possibly more elegant solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/XcFxQ/104/

```
<div class="my_img"></div>

.my_img{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:url(http://www.deshow.net/d/file/animal/2009-07/cute-kitten-631-4.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100px;
    transition:all 2s;
    -moz-transition:all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:all 2s; /* Opera */
    display:block;    
}

.my_img_large{
   height:400px;
   background-size: 4000px 400px;    
}

$('.my_img').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('my_img_large')) {
        $(this).removeClass('my_img_large');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('my_img_large');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I followed your elegant solution and  I did some modification in order to prevent image stretching however I dont seem to be able to expend my div anymore, just the background. Do you know why ? http://jsfiddle.net/ht5F8/

Comment: Which div do you mean Oreki?  Do you mean <div class="my_img"></div>?

Comment: Yes, my_img, as you can see in the exemple I linked, I can "zoom" but can't expend the div itself.

Comment: How do you need to expand the div?  I am not sure of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because in my example I have a "zoom" effect due to the fact that my div doesn't expand along with the background. I'd like my div to expand on height, this way I can see the full height of the background picture.

Comment: I found out the solution, I specified the proprieties in jquery, Thanks a lot again ! I learned a lot from this !

Comment: Please upvote or accept answer if it helped you. Glad you figured it out!